# How to use a Google Cloud Function to add a new value in a document created on Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want add a progressive counter like 'G0001', 'G0002' ... 'G0010' when a document is created on my Firestore. I create this document on my web app using Firestore API. I want trigger the function when I create a new document and set a new field like `{'code': 'G0001'}`. Also, I must read a document from Firestore to get the last code added.

**Example:**

Document created normally on web app:

```
{
'name': 'Augusto',
'age': 28,
}
```

Document to store on Firestore changed by Function

```
{
'name': 'Augusto',
'age': 28,
'code': 'G0001'
}
```

I created a node project with `firebase init` and my `index.ts` have it:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

exports.createNewGrupoDeInsumos = functions.firestore
.document('collection-name')
.onCreate((snap,context) => {

});
```

ps: I don't know when I set the collection name, I think that is like above.

Comment: Maybe you could get the collection and sort it by "code" via a query in order to get the largest value

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "I don't know when I set the collection name, I think that is like above"?

Comment: I've written an answer, see below. I would suggest that you try to implement one of these approaches and if you encounter some problems, just ask for help (and share your existing code :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain a global counter in your database. For that, just create a single document, for example under a collection named `counterDocCollection` and with an id equal to `counterDocCollection` and a numeric field named `counter`.

Then, in you Cloud Function, you need to increment the counter, read the new value and use it to generate the `Gxxxx` value.

There are two methods, depending on the frequency of update of this counter. As a matter of fact, in Firestore, you can only update a single document about once per second. So, the two methods are:

1. If you need to update the (single) counter document **more that once per second**, you need to use a Distributed counter. There is a dedicated documentation item for that, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters
2. If you update the counter document less frequently, you can use the [`increment`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FieldValue?authuser=0#static-increment) method of [`FieldValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FieldValue).  See also https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?authuser=0#increment_a_numeric_value

---

To get the counter document, just use the Admin SDK, as follows:

```
const counterDoc = admin.firestore().collection('counterDocCollection').doc('counterDocCollection');
```

---

To use the [`increment`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FieldValue?authuser=0#static-increment) method in a Cloud Function, do as follows:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
//.....

const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;
//.....

exports.createNewGrupoDeInsumos = functions.firestore
.document('collection-name')
.onCreate((snap,context) => {

    //.....

    const counterDoc = admin.firestore().collection('counterDocCollection').doc('counterDoc');

    return counterDoc.update({
       counter: FieldValue.increment(1);
    })
    .then(() => {
        return counterDoc.get();
    })
    .then(counterDoc => {
       const newCounterValue = doc.data().counter;

       //use newCounterValue to generate the Gxxxx value
       //Set the value of code in your initial doc

       return .....

});
```

Comment: I've questions. 1. This `.document('collection-name')` is wrong, because I found that G.C.F. can't refer the collections, just documents like `.document('collection-name/docName')`, but I can solve it ( I think ). 2. What this function must return? Why have two `then()` ? 3. How I set the value to document counter and set the new value `GXXXX` to my specific document created? 4. The function is the best way? I can do it on local app too.

Comment: This is alot of questions :-) Let's answer them one by one. 1/ Yes, a Cloud Firestore trigger must always point to a document and cannot point to a collection. But you can use wildcards. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?authuser=0#wildcards-parameters

Comment: 2/ Firestore methods (i.e. `update()`, `get()`, etc..) are asynchronous and return `promises()`. In the Cloud Function you need to chain these promises. See the official video series for more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series

Comment: 3/ I would suggest you give a try! :-) You'll get the current document through snap, which is a `DocumentSnapshot`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.html and the `ref` property. Then use the `update()` method. I will be happy to look at your code if you have problems when trying!

Comment: 4/ It depends if this counter is shared by all the users or not. If you increment the counter on the local app, two users may generate the same counter value.

Comment: Thank you for your help, everything is working. I be afraid because I must make several queries on database to make a simple thing, like read, increment and update. Hope that is no problem.